# Volver al inicion de otra funcion en C

Tags: c, funciones

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#include"jugador.h"

void jugador(){
 int e;

 printf("\n Menu jugador\n");
do{printf("Eleccion:");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%i",&e);
  switch(e){
   case 1:printf("Crear plantilla"); break;
   case 2:configuracion_plantilla(&e); break;
   case 3:printf("Listar plantilla"); break;
   case 4:printf("Eliminar plantilla"); break;
   case 5:printf("Ranking"); break;
   case 6:exit (-1); break;
   default: puts("Vuelva a elegir la eleccion\n");
   }
  }while(e>6);

 }


 void configuracion_plantilla(int *e){    //dentro del usuario y de la configuracion de 
                                          //la plantilla pues iria esta funcion
 int o;

 system("cls");
 printf("\n Menu jugador\n");
 printf("Configuracion plantilla\n");

do{printf("Eleccion:");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%i",&o);
  switch(o){
   case 1:printf("Lista de jugadores en plantilla"); break;
   case 2:printf("Lista de jugadores disponibles"); break;
   case 3:printf("A�adir jugador a plantilla"); break;
   case 4:printf("Eliminar jugador de plantilla"); break;
   case 5: e=7; system("cls"); break;
   default: puts("Vuelva a elegir la eleccion\n");
   }
  }while(e>5);


 }
```

Me gustaria poder volver al principio de la funcion jugador una vez que en que dentro de configuracion de plantilla elija la opcion volver. Si alguno sabe la respuesta lo agradeceria mucho ya que por mucho que pienso la solucion no la encuentro y la necesito para poder seguir avanzando en el trabajo de clase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, te recomiendo antes de que te pongas a hacer las funciones las declares:

> void jugador(); void configuracion_plantilla(int *e);

Había unos cuantos errores con las referencias y los apuntadores, te recomiendo repases esos temas.

El problema era tu condicion del do while de la funcion jugador, solo cambiala a distinto de o sea e!=6

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#include"jugador.h"
void jugador();
void configuracion_plantilla(int *e);

void jugador(){
 int e;

do{
 printf("\n Menu jugador\n");
  printf("Eleccion:");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%i",&e);
  switch(e){
   case 1:printf("Crear plantilla"); break;
   case 2:configuracion_plantilla(&e); break;
   case 3:printf("Listar plantilla"); break;
   case 4:printf("Eliminar plantilla"); break;
   case 5:printf("Ranking"); break;
   case 6:exit (-1); break;
   default: puts("Vuelva a elegir la eleccion\n");
   }
  }while(e!=6);

 }


 void configuracion_plantilla(int *e){    //dentro del usuario y de la configuracion de 
                                          //la plantilla pues iria esta funcion
 int o;

 system("cls");
 printf("\n Menu jugador\n");
 printf("Configuracion plantilla\n");

do{printf("Eleccion:");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%i",&o);
  switch(o){
   case 1:printf("Lista de jugadores en plantilla"); break;
   case 2:printf("Lista de jugadores disponibles"); break;
   case 3:printf("A�adir jugador a plantilla"); break;
   case 4:printf("Eliminar jugador de plantilla"); break;
   case 5: *e=7; system("cls"); break;
   case 6: {printf("Salir"); break;}
   default: puts("Vuelva a elegir la eleccion\n");
   }
  }while(*e>5);

    
 }

 int main() {

     jugador();
     return 0;
 }
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final lo que hice fue volver a llamar a la función jugador cuando dentro de configuracion_jugador eligiese la 5, ya que era volver y de esta forma también me va perfecto.
Muchas gracias aun así

Comment: Hola, de nada que bueno que pudiste solucionar tu problema.
Como recomendación te diría que cambiarás la condición del do while, debido a que sería más eficiente que volver a llamar de nuevo a la función.
Saludos...